# Hiding back button in viewDidLoad without animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm using `navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false)` to hide back button in my iOS10 app in `viewDidLoad`. When I do this, on navigation bar, back button label is briefly shown (it is fading out) in presenting animation instead not showing it at all, after screen change, button is gone.

How I can prevent it from happening?

Comment: set the property in viewWillAppear method

Comment: Hide the back buttom in the previous controller's `viewwilldisappear`

Comment: @SahebRoy how? Can You give me sample code?

Comment: I have tried with "self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true" as first line after super.viewDidLoad() . I tested this on simulator with slow animation, and i didn't get any fade effect for back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are going from Controller A to Controller B.
Currently you are applying `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` in the `viewDidLoad` of Controller B.

Add this very same code when you are pushing from A to B in Controller A's `viewWillDisappear` OR `prepareForSegue` (if you are using segue)

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
}
```

A safer option is in `prepareForSegue` as `viewWillDisappear` will get called whenever this Controller A is going OFF-SCREEN. But in `prepareForSegue`, you can check that the following code will work only when its going from Controller A to Controller B, by the following

Suppose the segue connecting from Controller A to Controller B is named "SEGUE_NAME"

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_NAME"]){
       /*
        this means it is going from Controller A to Controller B
        via segue "SEGUE_NAME"
      */
      self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
     }
  }
```

I think this would be the swift version : Forgive me if the syntax isn't appropriate

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "SEGUE_NAME"){
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
    }
 }
```